# What is the difference between load tests and performance tests?

Tags: testing, load-testing, performance-testing

What is the difference between *load tests* and *performance tests*? Are *load tests* just a special type of *performance tests*? If so, could you provide an example of performance tests, which are *not* load tests?

Comment: Hope this is helpful - http://www.softwaretestinghelp.com/what-is-performance-testing-load-testing-stress-testing/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Terminology questions are always difficult because many definitions float around. Yet, most of the time "performance test" is a wide category of test in which we look at how the Software Under Test behaves from a technical point of view: time to do some computation, response time of API or UI, memory used on the machine, disk footprint etc. And "load test" is the special case where you check your SUT under heavy load (lots of connections to your server for example).

An example of perf test that is not load test? For example "longevity test": test how your SUT behaves when it runs (under normal load) for a long time (several days/weeks). This test might highlight a memory or thread leakage, or you could discover that a given log file become huge, or you could discover that after some time, for some reasons, the system become unstable.